# Using a C# WinForms control in a C++/CLI (WinForms) application

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli, controls

How do I use a WinForms control written in C#, in a WinForms C++/CLI application ? If at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added a reference to the C# project or dll? Then you might have to add the control to the Toolbox